# XSLT chaining or combining xsl:copy-of and xsl:copy

Tags: xslt, xsd, wsdl, extract, chaining

I've got the following two XSL transforms that I would like to chain together in one XSL file.

The first transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/s0:definitions/s0:types/xs:schema"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the second transform (using the output of the first as input):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='ServiceAuth']"/>
<xsl:template match="/xs:schema/xs:import[@namespace='http://www.somecompany.com/serviceAuth/ ']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'm aiming to accomplish with this, is to copy only the xs:schema node (and all it's children) from a WSDL whilst at the same time removing two nodes from inside the xs:schema node.

How do I chain these two together in one XSL or is there an even better way to accomplish the above objective?

Below is the WSDL input file that should serve as input to the first transform:

```
<s0:definitions name="CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility" targetNamespace="http://www.somecompany.com/" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:s2="http://www.somecompany.com/" xmlns:s3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
   <s0:types>
      <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:auth="http://www.somecompany.com/serviceAuth/" xmlns:cbs="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:esb="http://www.somecompany.com/esbTypes/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.somecompany.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xs:import namespace="http://www.somecompany.com/esbTypes/" schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1:5000/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility?SCHEMA%2FVodacom+Services%2FInfrastructure+Services%2FSchemas%2FXSD_ESBTypes"/>
         <xs:import namespace="http://www.somecompany.com/serviceAuth/ " schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1:5000/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility?SCHEMA%2FVodacom+Services%2FInfrastructure+Services%2FSchemas%2FXSD_ServiceAuth"/>
         <xs:simpleType name="DESTINATION_MSISDN">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:maxLength value="11"/>
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:simpleType name="STRING_13">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:simpleType name="STRING_20">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:complexType name="UPGRADE_TYPE_DETAILS">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isber" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isreward" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="code" type="cbs:STRING_20"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="QUALIFIES_FOR_UPGRADE_DETAILS">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isaveragespentmet" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="is7daypremature" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="upgradepossible" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="upgradeduedate" type="cbs:STRING_13"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UpgradeType" type="cbs:UPGRADE_TYPE_DETAILS"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ServiceAuth">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Username" type="auth:Username"/>
                  <xs:element name="Password" type="auth:Password"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="GetUpgradeEligibilityRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="TSORequest" type="cbs:getUpgradeEligibilityRequestElement"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="GetUpgradeEligibilityResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TSOID" type="esb:TSOID"/>
                  <xs:element name="TSOResponse" type="cbs:getUpgradeEligibilityResponseElement"/>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TSOResult" type="esb:TSOResult"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:complexType name="getUpgradeEligibilityRequestElement">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="MSISDN" type="cbs:DESTINATION_MSISDN"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="getUpgradeEligibilityResponseElement">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="MSISDN" type="cbs:DESTINATION_MSISDN"/>
               <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="QualifiesForUpgrade" type="cbs:QUALIFIES_FOR_UPGRADE_DETAILS"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
   </s0:types>
   <s0:message name="GetUpgradeEligibilityRequestMessage">
      <s0:part element="s1:ServiceAuth" name="ServiceAuth"/>
      <s0:part element="s1:GetUpgradeEligibilityRequest" name="GetUpgradeEligibilityRequest"/>
   </s0:message>
   <s0:message name="GetUpgradeEligibilityResponseMessage">
      <s0:part element="s1:GetUpgradeEligibilityResponse" name="GetUpgradeEligibilityResponse"/>
   </s0:message>
   <s0:portType name="esbTransactionPort">
      <s0:operation name="getUpgradeEligibility">
         <s0:input message="s2:GetUpgradeEligibilityRequestMessage"/>
         <s0:output message="s2:GetUpgradeEligibilityResponseMessage"/>
      </s0:operation>
   </s0:portType>
   <s0:binding name="getUpgradeEligibilityEsbTransactionBinding" type="s2:esbTransactionPort">
      <s3:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <s0:operation name="getUpgradeEligibility">
         <s3:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
         <s0:input>
            <s3:header message="s2:GetUpgradeEligibilityRequestMessage" part="ServiceAuth" use="literal"/>
            <s3:body parts="GetUpgradeEligibilityRequest" use="literal"/>
         </s0:input>
         <s0:output>
            <s3:body parts="GetUpgradeEligibilityResponse" use="literal"/>
         </s0:output>
      </s0:operation>
   </s0:binding>
   <s0:service name="getUpgradeEligibilityEsbTransactionBindingQSService">
      <s0:port binding="s2:getUpgradeEligibilityEsbTransactionBinding" name="getUpgradeEligibilityEsbTransactionBindingQSPort">
         <s3:address location="http://VESB14-PRD:7701/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility"/>
      </s0:port>
   </s0:service>
</s0:definitions>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a third stylesheet that compose those two performing the same transformation as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="s0:definitions/s0:types/xs:schema"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xs:schema/xs:element[@name='ServiceAuth']"/>
    <xsl:template match="xs:schema/xs:import[@namespace='http://www.somecompany.com/serviceAuth/']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:import href="stylesheet2.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="stylesheet1.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vFirst">
            <xsl:apply-imports/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($vFirst)/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:s2="http://www.somecompany.com/" xmlns:s3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:auth="http://www.somecompany.com/serviceAuth/" xmlns:cbs="http://www.somecompany.com/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility/" xmlns:esb="http://www.somecompany.com/esbTypes/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.somecompany.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.somecompany.com/esbTypes/" schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1:5000/CBS_GetUpgradeEligibility?SCHEMA%2FVodacom+Services%2FInfrastructure+Services%2FSchemas%2FXSD_ESBTypes"></xs:import>
    <xs:simpleType name="DESTINATION_MSISDN">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="11"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="STRING_13">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="13"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="STRING_20">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="20"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="UPGRADE_TYPE_DETAILS">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isber" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isreward" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="code" type="cbs:STRING_20"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="QUALIFIES_FOR_UPGRADE_DETAILS">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isaveragespentmet" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="is7daypremature" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="upgradepossible" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="upgradeduedate" type="cbs:STRING_13"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UpgradeType" type="cbs:UPGRADE_TYPE_DETAILS"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="GetUpgradeEligibilityRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TSORequest" type="cbs:getUpgradeEligibilityRequestElement"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType></xs:element>
    <xs:element name="GetUpgradeEligibilityResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TSOID" type="esb:TSOID"></xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TSOResponse" type="cbs:getUpgradeEligibilityResponseElement"></xs:element>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TSOResult" type="esb:TSOResult"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType></xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="getUpgradeEligibilityRequestElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="MSISDN" type="cbs:DESTINATION_MSISDN"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getUpgradeEligibilityResponseElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="MSISDN" type="cbs:DESTINATION_MSISDN"></xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="QualifiesForUpgrade" type="cbs:QUALIFIES_FOR_UPGRADE_DETAILS"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. This is why I love Stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched XSLT for quite some time - but I think you can do it iterativly instead of by applying templates.

Start by selecting `/s0:definitions/s0:types/xs:schema` - then go over all of it's children (`<xsl:for-each ...` If i recall correctly) and for each of them test if it is the node you want to omit. if not - use `copy-of`, otherwise just drop it

Also, if you run the XSLT using some java code, or ANY utility you can just pass the output of the 1st XSLT as the input of the 2nd XSLT.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first stylesheet is just selecting what is processed by the 2nd -- not doing any transformation itself, can't you just change copy-of to apply-templates, and import the 2nd stylesheet ? ( You don't really need to do any chaining. )

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<xsl:import href="stylesheet-2.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:definitions/s0:types/xs:schema"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Right. Thanks - I missed that. ( Just remove the leading slashes from those two templates match paths. )